# How do I send image in a pdf format when uploading to a local server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am uploading an image to a local server using .png extension. I want to upload the image with a .PDF extension. How?

Comment: What's wrong with just uploading the PDF in the same way as your PNG image?  They're both just files with different extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try just changing the extension by changing the name of the file when you upload it? ie. Just changing .png to .pdf